# Outside the loop Category name with link

Tags: link-category, categories

I want to display the category Name by using category ID with link to category page (out side the loop).

here is my code...

```
<a href="<?php get_category_link('23'); ?>"><?php echo get_the_category_by_id(23); ?></a>
```

it's ok, but only think is it's go to home page... instead of category page... something missing... which i'hv not understand...

Comment: Click the [check mark](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G1SEk.png) to mark the answer as The Solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `echo` your link:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link('23') ); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_category_by_id(23); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Then mark the answer as _the answer_, use the checkmark (✔).